# Java DAO implementation testing

Tags: java, junit, dao, hsqldb, mockito

This is a very simple DAO attempt I'd like to share.

My question is if this is a correct way to test a DAO. What I mean is that I'm verifying the SQL query and giving it return a mock. Then tell the mock to return these specific values and assert them?

I have updated the DAO to use **prepared statement** instead of simple Statement. Thanks.

```
public class PanelDao implements IO {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PanelDao.class);

    private Connection connection;

    public PanelDao() throws SQLException {
        this(MonetConnector.getConnection()); 
    }

    public PanelDao(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Panel panel) throws SQLException {
        final String query = "INSERT INTO panels VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
        final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, panel.getId());
        statement.setString(2, panel.getColor());
        statement.setDate(3, (new Date(panel.getPurchased().getTime())) );
        statement.setDouble(4, panel.getCost());
        statement.setDouble(5, panel.getSellingPrice());
        statement.setBoolean(6, panel.isOnSale());
        statement.setInt(7, panel.getUserId());

        LOGGER.info("Executing: "+query);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Panel object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();      
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Panel object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();      
    }

    @Override
    public Panel find(String id) throws SQLException {
        final String query = "SELECT * FROM panels WHERE id = ? ";
        final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, id);

        LOGGER.info("Executing: "+query);
        final ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        final Panel panel = new Panel();
        if (result.next()) {
            panel.setId(result.getString("id"));
            panel.setColor(result.getString("color"));
        }
        return panel;       
    }
}
```

And the test class

```
public class PanelDaoTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private PanelDao panelDao;

    @Mock 
    private Connection connection;

    @Mock
    private Statement statement;

    @Mock
    private ResultSet result;

    private Panel panel;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    @Before
     public void init() throws SQLException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
        panel = new Panel("AZ489", "Yellow", new Date(), 10.00, 7.50, true, 1);
    }

   @Test
   public void testSave() throws SQLException {
        Mockito.when(connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO panels VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )")).thenReturn(statement);
        panelDao.save(panel);
        Mockito.verify(statement).executeUpdate();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() throws SQLException {
        Mockito.when(connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM panels WHERE id = ? ")).thenReturn(statement);
        Mockito.when(statement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(result);
        Mockito.when(result.next()).thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.when(result.getString("id")).thenReturn("AZ489");
        Mockito.when(result.getString("color")).thenReturn("Yellow");
        Panel panel = panelDao.find("AZ489");
        assertEquals("AZ489",panel.getId());
        assertEquals("Yellow",panel.getColor());
        Mockito.verify(statement).executeQuery();
     }
}
```

---

### 2.0 Testing DAO with HSQLDB

**After taking into account your feedback** I decided to use HSQLDB for real database testing. Please find this as a resource if tackling similar problems.

```
public class PanelDao implements IO {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PanelDao.class);

    private Connection connection;

    /**
     * Default constructor is using Monet connector
     */
    public PanelDao() throws SQLException {
        this(MonetConnector.getConnection()); 
    }

    public PanelDao(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Panel panel) throws SQLException {
        final String query = "INSERT INTO panels VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
        final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, panel.getId());
        statement.setString(2, panel.getColor());
        statement.setDate(3, (new Date(panel.getPurchased().getTime())) );
        statement.setDouble(4, panel.getCost());
        statement.setDouble(5, panel.getSellingPrice());
        statement.setBoolean(6, panel.isOnSale());
        statement.setInt(7, panel.getUserId());

        LOGGER.info("Executing: "+query);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Panel object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();      
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Panel object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();      
    }

    @Override
    public Panel find(String id) throws SQLException {
        final String query = "SELECT * FROM panels WHERE id = ? ";
        final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, id);

        LOGGER.info("Executing: "+query);
        final ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        if (result.next()) {
            final Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.setId(result.getString("id"));
            panel.setColor(result.getString("color"));
            panel.setPurchased(new Date(result.getDate("purchased").getTime()));
            panel.setCost(result.getDouble("cost"));
            panel.setSellingPrice(result.getDouble("selling_price"));
            panel.setOnSale(result.getBoolean("on_sale"));
            panel.setUserId(result.getInt("user_id"));
            return panel;
        }
        return null;        
    }
}
```

and the Test class:

```
public class PanelDaoTest {

    private PanelDao panelDao;
    private Panel panel;

    /* HSQLDB */
    private static Server server;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static Connection connection;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws SQLException {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        server = new Server();
        server.setAddress("127.0.0.1");
        server.setDatabaseName(0, "bbtest");
        server.setDatabasePath(0, ".");
        server.setPort(9000);
        server.start();
        PanelDaoTest.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9000/bbtest", "SA", "");
        PanelDaoTest.statement = PanelDaoTest.connection.createStatement();
    }

    @Before
    public void createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        PanelDaoTest.statement.execute(SqlQueries.CREATE_PANEL_TABLE);
        panelDao = new PanelDao(PanelDaoTest.connection);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws SQLException {
        panel = new Panel();
        panel.setId("A1");
        panel.setPurchased(new Date());
        panelDao.save(panel);
        assertNotNull(panelDao.find("A1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() throws SQLException {
        final String id = "45ZZE6";
        panel = Panel.getPanel(id);

        Panel received = panelDao.find(id);
        assertNull(received);

        panelDao.save(panel);
        received = panelDao.find(id);
        assertNotNull(received);
        assertEquals(panel.getId(), received.getId());
        assertEquals(panel.getColor(), received.getColor());
        assertEquals(panel.getPurchased().getDate(), received.getPurchased().getDate());
        assertEquals(panel.getPurchased().getMonth(), received.getPurchased().getMonth());
        assertEquals(panel.getPurchased().getYear(), received.getPurchased().getYear());
        assertEquals(panel.getCost(), received.getCost(),0.001);
        assertEquals(panel.getSellingPrice(), received.getSellingPrice(),0.001);
        assertEquals(panel.getUserId(), received.getUserId());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws SQLException {
        statement.executeUpdate(SqlQueries.DROP_PANEL_TABLE);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopServer() {
        server.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have, I'm going to use prepared statements thanks

Comment: That would be so much easier to read if you just did string concat instead of the StringBuilder, with no change in performance.  The comma and quote variables just make it extra hard as well.  append(comma).append(quote) instead of append(",'").  Each line would be much more readable with [+ "'" + panel.getXXX() + "',"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an in-memory database such as H2, to test that your SQL actually works.

- When you test your `save` method, your test should call `save`, then select the row from the database and assert that there is actually something there.
- When you test your `find` method, your test should insert some rows in the database directly, then call `find` and assert that the desired row or rows were actually found.

Comment: H2 might be a little risky because of variances in SQL dialect and database implementation.  I would suggest setting up a unit test instance on the actual DB platform that you're going to be using... If you do decide to go with H2 make sure to set the appropriate [compatibility mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility).

Comment: @ach that is very sound advice.  My experience suggests that the differences in SQL and so on between H2 and other platforms are fairly minor, especially if you pick the right compatibility mode.  If there ARE bugs in your SQL, then a test against H2 will find them, 99 times out of 100.  By contrast, requiring a "real" database instance to be set up makes your JUnit or TestNG tests a little more unwieldy, slower, and harder to manage.  There are pluses and minuses to both approaches, certainly; this may be one of those "do what works for you" situations.

Comment: @DavidWallace, with your sentence (If there ARE bugs in your SQL, then a test against H2 will find them, 99 times out of 100.) it stops being UNIT test. To be a proper unit test you have to trust it every single time it runs.

Comment: @frantakocourek You're absolutely right.  That's why I didn't call it a unit test.  Also, what I meant was that 99 out of 100 SQL bugs will be found by a test that uses H2 - I didn't mean that the behaviour of these tests would be non-deterministic.  One of the benefits of using an in-memory database is that you can make your tests deterministic.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should not create SQL queries by concatenation, because it's vulnerable to SQL injection. Use `PreparedStatement`s instead.

Actually, it doesn't make much sense to test DAO this way. Your tests only verify that your DAO passes values back and forth correctly, but it doesn't cover the real complexity that lies in correctness of SQL queries issued by your DAO.

In other words, if you want to test your DAOs you need to create integration test that involves real database. This way you can verify that SQL queries issued by your DAO are correct.

Comment: Is the point that a DAO should not be mocked and rather tested using either a real database or database testing framework? I see that with mocks you cant test the sql queries only verify that we are calling a method which is returning an object which you are giving it to return.. pointless?

Comment: @locke Standard mocking techniques are more useful in testing your Service layer (for example), where the _code_ is what constitutes difficult logic, or where you need to create mocks to test your classes in isolation (for example, you'd want to mock your DAOs).  Generally most DAOs contain very simple code, and the queries are what make up most of the complexity.  In this scenario traditional mocking isn't that useful.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really think that method of testing is really buying you anything, and the test code is extremely brittle.  I would use something like [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) that allows you to "mock" your database.  This will actually allow you to test the correctness of your queries.